# Select records with same value of another (MySql)

Tags: mysql, select

I have a mysql table that has a column "my_set", a non-unique key, and another column "my_element", a unique key. Each my_sel value can correspond to multiple my_element values, whereas each my_element corresponds to only one my_set.
All values of theese two columns are integers unsigned (11).

Starting from a my_element value, in a single query and without nested selects, I need to find all other my_elements that has same my_set.

The solution I would think was nested select

```
    select my_element 
    from table 
    where my_set = (
      select my_set 
      from table 
      where my_element = <elementValue>
    )
```

But, as I explained, I'd like to find a better, maybe faster way to do it without subselect, as performance is being an issue due to the huge number of similar queries in the db scheduled maintenance phase.

Also, better db structure advice could be appreciated, but currently db refactoring is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but I will try to answer from what I understood.
I think you need to use self join to get all the elements related to given element( which are related by same my_set). Try the below query.

```
select t2.my_element 
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.my_set = m2.my_set and t2.my_element <> t1.my_element
where t1.my_element = "element";
```

If it does not work. Create a sql fiddle with sample data, that would make it easy for us.

Comment: This achieves what I need, but isn't possible to do this without a join, is it?

Comment: It seems to use as much as time as a subselect, though I had not time to test it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query. If i understand it correctly, use the left outer join between two tables to get the ordered set of set and element.

```
select 
    mysetid,
    myelementid
from 
    tableset a 
left outer join 
    tableset b
on 
    a.setid = b.setid
order by 
    a.setid,b.elementid
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this perform another table scan similarly to a subselect?